# How to find the videos downloaded with YouTube HD app

Tags: lumia, video

I'm using **Nokia Lumia 525** and I'm facing a strange issue. I've downloaded some videos via the [YouTube HD](http://windowsphone.com/s?appId=0dcbf01a-e366-4af2-aba0-909f7d4e0a65) app to my phone. Currently it using phone memory. I can see the videos and play it in downloads inside the app but not from music&video in phone. My phone memory is almost full and I've to move that videos to SD card. I checked for the videos which is downloaded via YD through my lap inside the phone memory , but I couldn't see.

Can anyone help me to find out where the videos are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Phone Apps are using [isolated storage](http://jeffblankenburgdotcom.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-15-isolated-storage/) which is hidden from normal users as well as other applications. So you can't find the files in isolated storage or can't explore with any other apps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any alternate way for downloading youtube videos to my phone?

Comment: There are some file downloader apps which can serve as ftp server.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to move videos from YD to sd card.There is a option to send videos over BT from phone to BT Supported PC. I send it to my lap and then forward it to SD card using lap. But it is very difficult to done like this for this simple thing and I hope the problem will solved in coming updates.!!!!

Comment: Worth writing a review in the store for the app, and highlight the difficulty, which may help others, and make the developers aware...

Comment: But I am unable to send the video from Youtube App to my BT supported laptop...please tell me a way...

Comment: Which youtube downloader are you using?

Comment: I also used YoutubeHD with my Nokia 920. The app says that videos can be transferred via bluetooth, but I couldn't figure out how. @Kiran, How did you do it?

Comment: Checkout the videos in douwnloaded section of this app and there is a symbol of blutooth in right side of everyvideo you downloaded. You can click on that symbol and transfer into anydevice.

Answer (score 1):

You could try UC Browser. It can download videos. And you could save them and see them in your phone, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can download youtube videos MyTube from store.
download videos then you can see downloaded videos in download collection. Then click on save icon. It will ask for save to music app? click on ok.

Now you will be able to them in phone memory->music folder. Later you can change format from .mp3 to .mp4. Then you can able to see these videos in pre installed video application.