# Videos are not showing through filemanager which was downloaded through uc broswer

Tags: video, 8.1-update-1, nokia-lumia-630, downloads, uc-browser

I have Windows lumia 630 (8.1 update) updated UC browser & tube mate also, videos also downloads but thing is these videos are not searchable from file manager in either the Memory card or in phone. It acquires the space but can’t able to find the place where it is situated/placed.

Comment: Is it just on the phone or you are unable to see the files after connecting to PC as well ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question lies in the fact that Windows Phone Apps uses "isolated storage" to store anything on your device. So, if you have downloaded anything from any app be it UC Browser or Youtube Downloader, you can't access it other than from within that App. You can access the file downloaded through the "downloaded files" section in UC browser. Let me know if any more concerns.

Thanks to this question:
[How to find the videos downloaded with YouTube HD app](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3386/how-to-find-the-videos-downloaded-with-youtube-hd-app?rq=1)

Comment: No. You are wrong. I downloaded a video in ucbrowser app and was successful in moving the video to different location. I moved the file to another location and was able to see in photos. I was able to access the file outside of ucbrowser

Comment: The answer is 3 month old. I didn't find any solution at that time. I am no longer using UC web. So, it would be great if you could just edit your answer and add the steps as to how you were able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows is a closed platform you can't view your downloaded files directly however you can do this in a few simple steps.

- Open UC browser
- Go to downloaded video
- Tap an hold it
- It will give you a pop-up menu
- From this menu select "Export to SD card".

And nnow you are done. Now navigate to the file manager app and goto UCdownloads folder. Here you'll find your video. Now freely copy, move or share it.

Answer (score 0):

If UC is downloaded to the sd card all the files are stored in

f:\WPSystem\AppData\local\Packages\Ucmobil~1\LocalState\Download

Here f:\ is your sd letter and ucmobil~1 is the only folder that begins with those letters in the packages folder

Good luck opening anything under there though. They all seem to require some kind of browser authentication to access or something. They wont open in anything else so if you deleted uc browser you'll have to beg the devs for some work around.... that they probably wont give.